# checking with boolean values not working correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

please see edit #1 - I'm working on a Vue.js and am changing a co-workers code. The goal is to check that we have a user in our Vuex store and if not alert the user to login / signup. When not logged in, it is returning false but the 'TOGGLE_LIKED' is still being called.

It currently looks like this:

```
check(){
  if (typeof this.$store.state.user === 'undefined' || !this.$store.state.user) {
    alert('please signin in the upper-right'); /* eslint-disable-line no-alert */
    return false;
  }else{
    return true;
  }
},
toggleLiked() {
  if (this.check()) {
    this.isRunningToggle = true;
    this.$store.dispatch('TOGGLE_LIKED', this.item).then(() => {
      this.isRunningToggle = false;
    });
```

What is wrong with the code so that if you are not logged in, the 'TOGGLE_LIKED' path isn't called?

#### edit #1

so if I switch to an event-bus call like this:

```
  if (EventBus.$emit('checkLoggedIn')) {
    this.isRunningToggle = true;
    this.$store.dispatch('TOGGLE_LIKED', this.item).then(() => {
      this.isRunningToggle = false;
    });
  }
```

with checkLoggedIn in the root component as:

```
  EventBus.$on('checkLoggedIn', () => {
    console.log(this.$store.state.user); 
    if (typeof this.$store.state.user === 'undefined' || !this.$store.state.user) {
      alert('please signin in the upper-right'); 
      return false;
    }else{
      alert('this is true');
      return true;
    }
  });
```

The first alert is called but the second ISN'T. So if we are returning false, why does the check return "effectively" true?

Comment: Simplify to `if (!this.$store.state.user) `

Comment: have you checked what is the value for `this.$store.state.user`? if the value is `{}`, `this.check()` will return true

Comment: I think this.check() returns a function, which is returning as true because it is defined. Set a variable to the function and then check the value of that variable

Comment: What's the valley of `user`? `console.log()` it.